# Center input fields in form

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a login form that is on the center of the page. The FORM is already in the right place with the right size. However, the two inputs are aligned to the left and I want them to be centered. The following code does not work. Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
      <form action="/new" method="POST">
        <input class="loginField" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address"></input>
        <input class="loginField" type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password"></input>
      </form>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.loginField {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `form-control` class to alter the default behavior of [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) inputs.

*I altered your HTML so it's mobile first, this wont effect the text being centered if it's unnecessary for your needs tho.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
#loginForm {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#loginForm .form-control {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <form id="loginForm">
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
<hr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `class="text-center"` to your form

```
<form class="text-center" action="/new" method="POST">
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/fuhuli/1/edit?html,css,js,output)***

Logically, if you don't want *all* your form's text to be centered, wrap your inputs inside a i.e: `<div>` and add the class to that DIV instead.